# Greetings, I'm struggling to get this Jet SQL query to tell me how many race wins a driver has on different tracks

Tags: sql, jet

Here's the SQL:

```
SELECT  
    SessionResults.Driver, 
    COUNT(IIF(SessionResults.Place=1, 1, NULL)) AS Wins,  
    ROUND(AVG([SessionResults].[Place]), 2) AS [Avg Race Placing],  
    ROUND(AVG([SegmentData].[SegPlace]),2) AS [Avg Heat Placing], 
    COUNT(SessionResults.TotalLaps) AS [Total Laps], 
    EventHistory.TrackID AS [Track/Layout], 
    MAX(EventHistory.Date) AS [Last Race]
FROM 
    SessionResults, SegmentData, EventHistory
WHERE 
    (((SessionResults.EventID) = [EventHistory].[EventID]) 
      AND ((SegmentData.EventID) = [SessionResults].[EventID]))
GROUP BY 
    SessionResults.Driver, EventHistory.TrackID;
```

I've tried all kinds of different approaches but the second expression in the select never produces the right results. Does anybody know how one can count the SessionResults.Place columns that have a value of 1?

I've tried all kinds of methods. I've been able to count in that position other column values accidently, I've counted negative numbers, and completely inaccurate numbers. I can do a specific select and get the right data, just not in a complex Select statement like above.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**30 years!!** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: Thanks for the info. I'll certainly look into improving my code once I can get it to work.

Comment: As noted in your other thread, issue is due to fact tables have 1-to-many or many-to-many relationships. Probably have to aggregate one or all of the tables separately then join.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help. I'm studying JOIN's and will try figure out how to do this that way.